# Can the input of the blockproc function in matlab be variable based on the evaluated block?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I just want to know if it is possible to pass a variable input to the blockproc funtion. For example:

```
fun = @(block_struct) my_fun(block_struct.data, x);
out = blockproc(im, [N N], fun);
```

I would that the input x changes for each block. In particular x should be equal to the number of the block, e.g. x = 1 for the first block, x = 2 for the second block, etc.
Is this possible?